# Is there a safe way to close or revive a frozen software updater?

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

The screen within the window has dimmed and nothing is changing.

I know I should file a bug report, but in the mean time, is there a way to safely close the software updater, in case Should I need to restart my computer?

The minimize and close window buttons in the title bar still seem to be functional. If the word "finished" is present, is it safe to close the window?

[image]